# Reusing Registrations with Castle Windsor Installers?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

We currently have 2 web applications, one is a front end customer facing application while the other is an administrative backend application.  What we noticed is that alot of registration is duplicated between the 2 applications.  Example, RavenDb Setup. For example both applications have this code in the asp.net global.asax

```
        container.Register(
           Component.For<IDocumentStore>()
               .UsingFactoryMethod(x =>
               {
                   var docStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };
                   docStore.Initialize();
                   return docStore;
               }).LifestyleSingleton()
           );
```

We refactored this code out into an installer and placed it in an assembly called CastleWindsor.RavenDbInstaller that can be referenced and reused by both applications.

```
public class RavenDbInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
           Component.For<IDocumentStore>()
               .UsingFactoryMethod(x =>
               {
                   var docStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };
                   docStore.Initialize();
                   return docStore;
               }).LifestyleSingleton()
           );
    }
}
```

**All is fine but is this the recommended approach to reusing registration logic between applications??**

Also, What happens when an installer in a seperate assembly has a dependency on another class.  How should this be handled.  For example, What if my ravendb connectionstring should not be hardcoded and should be attached to a ApplicationConfiguration class.  How do i deal with this dependency in regards to my CastleWindsor.RavenDbInstaller Assembly and the installer class it contains?

```
public class RavenDbInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
           Component.For<IDocumentStore>()
               .UsingFactoryMethod((c, y) =>
               {
                   var connectionStringName = c.Resolve<IApplicationConfiguration>().ConnectionStringName; // <---- How do i deal with this dependency?
                   var docStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName };
                   docStore.Initialize();
                   return docStore;
               }).LifestyleSingleton()
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the same implemetation for IApplicationConfiguration for  backend and frontend then it makes sense to place it in CastleWindsor.RavenDbInstaller Assembly. Otherwise not.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would leave the installer into the assembly where the components it references are. You will not resolve a component that you don't install, or resolve a component you don't use, so separating both elements doesn't really make sense to me. Both application should reference a business component that uses RavenDB and also contains install elements.

Regarding your reference to the connection string, I would recommend adding a custom [resolver](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Resolvers&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to your castle installation that will be able to resolve your connection string from whatever source you need: this lets you resolve the connection string in the installer without having a reference on external components. Another bonus is that if you don't register a way to resolve the connection string you don't have to handle errors, the resolution will fail explicitly with the name of the connection string.

```
public class ConnectionStringResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    public bool CanResolve(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, Castle.Core.DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        var connectionStringInformation = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dependency.DependencyKey];

        return connectionStringInformation != null 
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringInformation.ConnectionString)
              &&
              TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dependency.TargetType)
               .CanConvertFrom(typeof(string));
    }

    public object Resolve(Castle.MicroKernel.Context.CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, Castle.Core.DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor
            .GetConverter(dependency.TargetType)
            .ConvertFrom(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dependency.DependencyKey].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Then your installer would be:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
       Component.For<IDocumentStore>()
           .UsingFactoryMethod((c, y) =>
           {
               var connectionStringName = container.Resolve("TheConnectionString");
               var docStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName };
               docStore.Initialize();
               return docStore;
           }).LifestyleSingleton()
       );
}
```